# Javascript functions in HTML table based game

Tags: javascript, html, function, html-table

This is my first question so go easy on me :)

I have a table with td's in my HTML each with its own id that corresponds to its xy value. E.g. :

```
<td id = Y9X1></td>
<td id = Y9X2></td>
```

And what I want to do is 'grab' that item using a function E.g. :

```
//the starting position of x and y
var x = 1;
var y = 1;

let id = 'Y' +y+'X'+x;

//grab the id 
function grabPoistion(id) {
    document.getElementById(id)
}
//move sprite on grid according to position
function moveSprite() {
    grabPoistion(id);
}
```

Here is what Im basically trying to do:

If x = 1 and y = 1 then move the 'player' to table cell with the id Y1X1.

This was my initial code, I was just hoping there was a way to speed this up without having to do a statement for each individual cell :

```js
function moveSprite() {
 if(x==1 && y==1) {
  //move the player in the table to td with id =     Y1X1
 }
 else if(x==2 && y==1) {
  //move the player in the table to td with id =     Y1X2
 } 
}
```

Comment: Not sure what issue you are facing with this code. However I do see that you are not returning the element from `grabPoistion` function.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Where and how do you call the `moveSprite` function? What is the sprite? Could you provide more context so we can understand what you try to achieve?

Comment: I added an edit to my question

Comment: Did my answer help you, or did you only accept it because there was nothing else? :-)

Comment: @baao no it did help :) I just got a bit confused with the function :                
  function move(direction) {
  [...table.rows].forEach(r => [...r.cells].forEach(c => c.innerText = ''));
  directions[direction]();
  table.rows[position.y].cells[position.x].innerText = 'x';
}                                                                                                                                        Thanks for your help though, I think it just might have went a bit over my head haha

Comment: :-) Nice, I wasn't sure if that's what you're looking for. `[...table.rows]` is [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). table.rows is an html collection, but we need an array to use forEach on it. That converted it to one. `directions[direction]()` picks the correct method from the directions object and calls it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with a table, you can easily use its `rows` and `cells`. There's usually no need to work with `id`s for `td`s. To be honest, I have no idea what you are asking, but I had this little piece of code lying around, that moves an x through a table, by pressing up, down, left, right arrow keys. I left `left` and `right` working for you, maybe you can get a grasp on how to select table rows and their cells inside of the table and implement up and down yourself. It should be fairly simple to extend on the script, too - it's intentionally pretty verbose.

```js
const directions = {
  '37': left,
  '39': right,
  '38': up,
  '40': down
},
table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0],
  position = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  }
table.rows[0].cells[0].innerText = 'x';

window.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  if (![37, 38, 39, 40].includes(e.keyCode)) return;
  move(e.keyCode);
})

function move(direction) {
  [...table.rows].forEach(r => [...r.cells].forEach(c => c.innerText = ''));
  directions[direction]();
  table.rows[position.y].cells[position.x].innerText = 'x';
}

function left() {
  if (position.x === 0) {
    if (position.y === 0) return;
    position.y -= 1;
    position.x = table.rows[position.y].cells.length - 1;
    return;
  }
  position.x -= 1;
}

function right() {
  if (position.x === table.rows[position.y].cells.length - 1) {
    if (position.y === table.rows.length - 1) return;
    position.y += 1;
    position.x = 0;
    return;
  }
  position.x += 1;
}

function up() {
  console.log('have fun implementing');
}

function down() {
  console.log('have fun implementing');
}
```

```css
tr, td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

td {
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

(click "run code snippet", then once inside the table)